# Is it possible to add custom drawable to imageView in an Android Home Screen Widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation, android-imageview, lottie

I'm doing an home screen widget for android and I want to use a Lottie animation on the widget. I know the `LottieAnimationView` is not supported as the widget only supports some views. But can I use this custom drawable [LottieDrawable](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieDrawable.java) to use in an ImageView on the widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sorry. You can only use drawable resources or bitmaps, not a `Drawable` object.

While your app has Lottie, your app is not rendering the app widget. The home screen renders the app widget. Hence, the `RemoteViews` system limits you to things that are part of the framework, that any home screen will be able to use.

Comment: I did not know the difference between drawable resources and drawable object. Is there any document confirming that? Thanks!

Comment: @PedroRomanoBarbosa: If you look at [the JavaDocs for `RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews), you will not find any methods that take a `Drawable` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Try something like this:

```
Paint p = new Paint(); 
p.setAntiAlias(true);
p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
p.setStrokeWidth(8);
p.setColor(0xFFFF0000);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, 
Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawArc(new RectF(10, 10, 90, 90), 0, 270, false, p);

RemoteViews views = new 
RemoteViews(updateService.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.canvas, bitmap);

ComponentName componentName = new 
ComponentName(updateService, 
DashboardAppWidgetProvider.class);
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = 
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(updateService);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, 
views);
```